# iOS Intercom crash when tapping default icon

Tags: ios, objective-c, intercom, intercom-ios

I'm using `Intercom` for iOS. `Version 2` is working fine. After upgrading to `Version 3.0.17`, and tapping the intercom icon, or after tapping back from the intercom messenger i got this error:
[image]

`[ICMInboxTitleView addTitleText]`is using a bad range

Can I do something in my app to fix this?
Now i cannot even call `[Intercom presentMessenger]`

Answer (score 0):

Check first your NSMutable Array, n check data parameters n value those fetch on server.

Comment: hi the nsmutable array is intercom side, as shown in the log. NSRange issue